# Address inputs and arrays

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have set up my phpmyadmin and everything is working correctly, however I have came across a problem that I never came across I tried to research it but I cant find a solution.

The problem is I have 3 separate input boxes for the user to enter their address like so: 
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgWtx.jpg "Input boxes".

This is some of the code:

```
$Line1 = $_POST['FirstLine']  ;
$Line2 = $_POST['City']  ;
$Line3 = $_POST['Postcode']  ;
$Array = array([$Line1] , [$Line2] , [$Line3]);
$Address = implode(', ' , $Array);

$sql = "INSERT INTO CT_expressedInterest (forename, surname ,  email , 
landLineTelNo , mobileTelNo, postalAddress, catID , sendMethod  ) VALUES 
('$forename' ,'$surname' ,'$email' ,'$landLineTelNo' ,'$mobileTelNo' 
,'$Address' ,'$catID' ,'$sendMethod' )";

echo $Address ;

...
```

I always get a error 'Array to string conversion'

These are my results in the database:

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovjLL.png "Results"

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What does it have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin it shows as 'Array, Array, Array' instead of the values such as 'street name, city, postcode'

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't mean that you should tag your question with it. Use SQL or the name of the actual DB i.e. MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `$Array = array([$Line1], [$Line2], [$Line3]);` to `$Array = array($Line1, $Line2, $Line3);`

Comment: I just tried you code, it got no error after removing the brackets as I said.

Comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in line 22

Comment: Line 22 `$Address = implode(', ' , $Array); `

Comment: You also need to remove the quotes around $address in your SQL `'$Address'`

Answer (score -2):

```
$Line1 = $_POST['FirstLine']  ;
$Line2 = $_POST['City']  ;
$Line3 = $_POST['Postcode']  ;
$Array = array($Line1 , $Line2 , $Line3);
$Address = implode(', ' , $Array);

$sql = "INSERT INTO CT_expressedInterest (forename, surname ,  email , 
landLineTelNo , mobileTelNo, postalAddress, catID , sendMethod  ) VALUES 
('$forename' ,'$surname' ,'$email' ,'$landLineTelNo' ,'$mobileTelNo' 
,'$Address' ,'$catID' ,'$sendMethod' )";

echo $Address ;
```

//Remove the square brackets in the $array